# Copy data from one existing row to another existing row except 3 column in scala data frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Need some help with this issue , I have one data frame where I have one row with all column having value(it may include null) but received one another row with same key except ID ,DOJ and status rest all other column are null, I need to copy all data from status=ACTIVE to status=UPDATE, where column are null in status=UPDATE.

```
    dfx.show()
+-----+-------+--------+--------+--------------+-------+
|id   | name  | address| post   |   DOJ        | status|
+-----+-------+--------|--------|--------------+-------+
|    4| a     |  xyz   | null   | 2021-10-29   | Active|
|    4| null  |  null  | null   | 2021-10-30   | Update|
+-----+-------+-------+---------|--------------+-------+
```

-- there can be multiple column with null value but ID ,DOJ and status will always have data in each row.

expected

```
+-----+-------+--------+--------+--------------+-------+
|id   | name  | address| post   | DOJ          | status|
+-----+-------+--------|--------|--------------+-------+
|    4| a     |  xyz   | null   | 2021-10-29   | Active|
|    4| a     |  xyz   | null   | 2021-10-30   | Update|
+-----+-------+--------+--------|--------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

My Spark syntax is a bit rusty, but this is roughly an approach you could take.

First create two separate data frames:

```scala
val updateDF = original.where(status = "Update").as("u")
val activeDF = original.where(status = "Active").as("a")
```

I am assuming there is only row per `id` in `activeDF`. If this is not the case you may need to add additional measures to achieve this (windowing?).

Then join the two and select the stuff you need, something like:

```scala
val nullsUpdated = updateDF
  .join(activeDF, col("u.id") === col("a.id"))
  .select(
      col("u.id") as "id",
      coalesce("u.name", "a.name") as "name",
      coalesce("u.address", "a.address") as "address",
      coalesce("u.post", "a.post") as "post",
      col("u.DOJ") as "DOJ",
      col("u.status") as "status"
    )
```

Then finally, to get the active rows back in, use unionAll:

```scala
result = activeDF.unionAll(nullsUpdated)
```

Comment: Thanks Erik for you reply, this will work if i know the list of column name, the scenario is for each different table the list of column and its name is change

Comment: @Code_rocks if you don't know the column names at compile time, you can query for them and construct the arguments to `select` and `join` dynamically.